# Zoom-in Zoom-out buttons on iphone 4s mobile safari, clicking button causes container div to be clicked, and flashes the div as a link

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, click, mobile-safari

for some reason on mobile devices like the iphone4s and ipad 3, when i click on buttons that have a click event handler, if i click on a zoomin or zoomout button, instead of handling the click, it flashes the whole container as a link, meaning it sets the containers background to black for a flash second, and the handler isn't called.

however when i zoom in on the button itself, the buttons are large enough and it works. why would it handle the container as a link when the container is not an anchor but just a div?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it seems that ios/mobile safari thinks im trying to tap the div instead of the button since the buttons are so small (my fault), so i used:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

so that the div wouldn't be highlighted.